# When should I use GeneratePartialMock and GenerateStub in Rhino.Mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to test a virtual method and while debuging in VS 2017, I can't enter the method to see what it is doing. It seems like the method isn't being called because I've instantiated it with GenerateStub from MockRepository.

What I'm trying to do is to enter my method and do stubs in the calls that I don't want it to enter and want to get the expected result to finally perform the algorithm.

For me it's confusing the difference between them.

My question is: when and why should I use GeneratePartialMock and GenerateStub in Rhino.Mocks?